# SimpleForm: SyntaxError in Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

Any idea on what could be wrong in this form?

Error:

```
vehicleTrack.html.erb:141: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block, expecting => ... params[:rangefrom_string]} do |f| @output_buffer.safe_appe... ... ^
```

This is my view:

```
   <%= simple_form_for '', url: convertTrackToArea_path, :method => :post, 
       { :controller => "vehicles", 
         :action => "convertTrackToArea", 
         :search => params[:search], 
         :rangefrom_string => params[:rangefrom_string]} do |f| %>
       <%= f.input :areano, :label => 'Areano' %>
       <%= f.button :submit, value: "Crear",:name => nil%>
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not used `simple_form` so my guess is you are passing the last last argument incorrectly and it wont take a hash as argument and it detects the argument as key and searching for a value so throws error that `=>` is missing, which is used to identify value in hash. So you can do something like this I suppose:

```
<%= simple_form_for '', 
:url => url_for(:action => 'convertTrackToArea', :controller => 'vehicles',:search => params[:search], 
     :rangefrom_string => params[:rangefrom_string]),
:method => 'post' do |f| %>
```

since you are specifying `controller` and `action` you dont need to mention `convertTrackToArea_path` . If that route is already setup, you can just use that like in your posted question and remove controller and action name like:

```
<%= simple_form_for '', :url => convertTrackToArea_path(:search => params[:search],:rangefrom_string => params[:rangefrom_string]),:method => 'post' do |f| %>
```